# Find the lattice of Galois Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am wondering what the lattice of subfield of $GF(p^{30})$ looks like. I know that it starts from $GF(p)$ and then $GF(p^2)$ and $GF(p^3)$, but then I am lost. And I looked it up online, but can't find anything related with $GF(p^{30})$. Thanks guys!

Comment: The subfields of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ are precisely the finite fields $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ where $d \mid n$ (exercise). So the lattice of subfields is the lattice of divisors of $n$. There's no particular reason to single out the case $n = 30$.

Comment: So that would be 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 30. I just don't know how to arrange them. I just write them out and that is it?

Comment: Or do I need to arrange them in a particular order? Like what goes above $GF(p^2)$? Either $GF(p^5)$ or $GF(p^6)$ works?

Comment: They're arranged by divisibility.

Comment: You figured out the subfields of $GF(p^{30})$.  To figure out the lattice, you have to also figure out which are also subfields of $GF(p^{15})$, etc.  Same reasoning.

Comment: @Slade Oh I get it! So $GF(p^2)$, $GF(p^3)$ and $GF(p^5)$ are on the same row, and $GF(p^6)$ goes above  $GF(p^2)$ and $GF(p^3)$, correct?

Comment: @J.doe Yes, that's exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

Just so we're all clear with this question, the lattice of $GF(p^{30})$ is isomorphic to the lattice of divisors of $30$, as shown in [this image](https://image.slidesharecdn.com/ch-2latticebooleanalgebra-140912063621-phpapp02/95/ch-2-lattice-boolean-algebra-25-638.jpg?cb=1410503860) and explained in the comments above.