# Definition of the term "Lattice of field extension"

Tags: field-theory

I was working on some field theory problems and I'm stuck at this particular point where a part of a question asks, "..... now draw the corresponding lattice of field extensions from $\mathbb{Q}$." I don't understand this specific question as in my text book I found no definition/information about this term "lattice of field extensions". I would be very happy if someone can explain this to me preferably with an example and how to "draw" these things.

Answer (score 1):

See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order))  for what lattice is (there are pictures there of diagrams as well). Field extensions are partially ordered by inclusion, and their "meet" is the intersection (intersections of field extensions of a fixed field are such a field extension again). The join is just the field generated by the union (all within some algebraic closure).

For an example, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1760518/4280).

Also see the examples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory), as well.

Comment: Wiki gives a definition in the absolute general sense I cant get the hang of the idea. Let s take $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ to be a field extension over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then do I have to order the elements in the extension field in some way? will the usual ordering  in $\mathbb{Q}$ still work in the extension?

Comment: @mudok no order on the field; but on its extensions.

Comment: E.g. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ have a common join (least upper bound) $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$

Comment: Sorry I still am unable to see the picture of a lattice of a field extension. May be Im too ignorant to see it.

Comment: @mudok Have you looked at the final 2 examples?